# More than 3 email addresses for a contact in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is there anyway to add more than three email addresses for a contact in outlook?
I need it and can't create another contact.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/add-more-than-3-email-addresses-contact-outlook-2003-a-t2507917.html) and [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31205508/how-to-add-a-4th-email-address.aspx) it looks like you can't - at least not in a way that will make them behave the same as the default three (in my experience, if Sue Mosher says it can't be done, it probably can't be done).

You should perhaps specify the version of Outlook you're using - perhaps something has changed since that post.

Answer (score 1):

This is a major hack, but it may be acceptable depending on exactly how you would use the additional addresses and how badly you want this: register a domain name with a provider like GoDaddy and use their email forwarding features to direct a single incoming address to multiple forwarded addresses.

Comment: nice out the box thinking

Answer (score 1):

Create an outlook distribution list and then add the distribution list as one of the e-mails.

Double clicking the distribution list within the contact will allow you to edit the list.